# KRL Search annotation rules for multiple domains, divs inserting for each domain whether domain matches or not

Tags: krl

My KRL search annotation ruleset contains 4-5 rules that each do annotation based on the domain in the search results. I am getting good results, in that the annotations are pretty much when and where they should. However, as I look at the source code in the browser, **each rule is inserting a div into the html whether any annotation should occur for that domain or not**. There is nothing on visible the page to suggest it, but I don't want to add any unnecessary code and keep this light.

**Is there a way to instruct those rules that do not annotate for a result to not place any code into the page?** (btw - right now I'm using all local data -  I will be doing a remote call later on after this is tested and realize that will solve this issue).

#### Two of my rules:

```js
rule search_annotate_party is active {
select using "google.com|bing.com/search|search.yahoo.com/search" setting()
every {
  emit <<
    function annotate_party(toAnnotate, wrapper, data) {
      if (data.domain == "www.mydomain.com" ) {
        wrapper.append("<div style='border: 1px dashed orange'><a href='http://www.mydomain.com/search.do?query=some+product' target='_blank'><img src=https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3287029/product_image.png width='100%'></a></div>");
        wrapper.show();
      }
    }
  >>;
  annotate:annotate("party") with
    annotator = <| annotate_party |>;
  }
}

rule search_annotate_jiffy is active {
select using "google.com|bing.com/search|search.yahoo.com/search" setting()
every {
  emit <<
    function annotate_jiffy(toAnnotate, wrapper, data) {
      if (data.domain == "www.hisdomain.com" ) {
        wrapper.append("<div style='border: 0px solid red'><img    src=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3287029/company_logo.jpg>");
        wrapper.show();
      }
    }
  >>;
  annotate:annotate("jiffy") with
    annotator = <| annotate_jiffy |>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "each rule is inserting a div into the html whether any annotation should occur for that domain or not". I can't seem to replicate that behavior. Can you show a DOM tree before and after the rule runs on a search result that shouldn't be annotated but is getting a div anyway?